# Como enviar emails entre usuários sem limites?

Tags: php

Boas Pessoal. Tenho uma aplicação em PHP que administra certos tipos de reunião.
Resumindo, uma pessoa cria uma reunião e isso faz com que a aplicação envie emails convidando outros usuários para essa reunião. Funcionava bem quando tinha poucas pessoas, mas agora o servidor de hospedagem está a limitar esses emails, ou seja, uns recebem e outros não (e a aplicação deixa de enviar qualquer email por um determinado período).

Isso tem feito com que eu perca usuários!!!

Como resolver isso? É possível ter um serviço externo em que eu possa somente mudar os dados do SMTP sem mexer na aplicação? No fundo o que eu gostaria era enviar quantos emails fossem necessários. Alguém tem uma ideia melhor? Obrigado.

Comment: Acredito que pode te ajudar: https://www.google.com/intx/pt-BR/work/apps/business/ Como nunca fiz nada desse tipo ainda, posso estar enganado... mas acredito que um e-mail corporativo pode ajudar....

Comment: http://mailchimp.com/, mas você terá que pagar e alterar a parte de envio de emails da sua aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal pelas informações. 
O que mais se enquadra no que eu preciso é o https://mandrillapp.com

Ele fornece o SMTP que eu preciso para inserir na aplicação sem que eu tenha que programar nada. E funciona muito bem até na versão free. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive o mesmo problema a algum tempo atrás, meu servidor me limitava a apenas 100 emails/hora. Resolvi contratando um dedicado no exterior, que é mais barato e não te limita.

Cuidado com os apps free. Pro meio corporativo pode ser perigoso.